# Star-continuity of a partially ordered, idempotent semiring implies Kleene Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've been looking into Kleene algebras for an upcoming presentation I'm giving on regular expressions.  I've read that (in an idempotent semiring with partial order $a\le b \iff a+b=b$) star-continuity, i.e.

$$xy*z = \sup(\underset{0\le i\le n}{\{xy^i z\}})$$

implies the four Kleene algebra axioms related to Kleene stars.

I'm stuck on how star-continuity implies this axiom:

$$1+xx^*\le x^*$$

I can show that it's true for $n\ge 1$:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
1+xx^* & = & 1 + \sup(\underset{0\le i\le n-1}{\{xx^i\}}) \\
 & = & x^0 + \sup(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\{x^i\}}) \\
& = & \sup({x^0}) +  \sup(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\{x^i\}}) \\
& = & \sup(\underset{0\le i\le n}{\{x^i\}}) \\
& = & x^*
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

(and if $1+xx^*=x^*$ then certainly $1+xx^*\le x^*$.)

However, this clearly won't work for $n=0$ so now I'm starting to question whether this is even a correct way to prove this implication.  Any hints?

Edit: I should add that I'm getting a lot of this out of the lecture notes from [Prof. Dexter Kozen's course](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs786/2004sp/).  My hangup is trying to interpret and understand the arguments therein.

Answer (score 0):

The thing I failed to realize was that star-continuity holds for all $n\ge 0$.

$$xy*z = \sup(\underset{0\le i\le n}{\{xy^i z\}}) \forall n\ge 0$$

So when doing the computation, we don't care that the $n$ at the start doesn't line up with $n+1$ at the end.  This isn't an inductive step, it's just a computation. Hence we can do this:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
1+xx^* & = & 1 + \sup(\underset{0\le i\le n}{\{xx^i\}}) \\
 & = & x^0 + \sup(\underset{1\le i\le n+1}{\{x^i\}}) \\
& = & \sup({x^0}) +  \sup(\underset{1\le i\le n+1}{\{x^i\}}) \\
& = & \sup(\underset{0\le i\le n+1}{\{x^i\}}) \\
& = & x^*
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

(and if $1+xx^*=x^*$ then certainly $1+xx^*\le x^*$.)

Comment: Part of my problem was that I proved that star-continuity implied the other two axioms (i.e. the two not symmetric to this one) inductively and so I was still in "induction mode."